# Error al configurar STATICFILES_DIRS en setting.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-urls

Me devuelve el siguiente error al querer utilizar static (archivos CSS, JS, IMAGENES. Parece que la configuración en Setting.py no la hago bien. ¿Qué sucede?:

ERROR:

**STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR.child('static')]**

**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'child'**

¿Sería correcta esta siguiente configuración de setting.py?

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR.child('static')]
```

Árbol de archivos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Se debe hacer así en setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
```

En el template al principio indicamos:

```
{% load static %}
```

Después en un template podemos añadir por ejemplo el css así:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/app.css' %}">
```